# Spring Boot With OpenShift get public url

Tags: spring-boot, openshift

I have deployed spring boot application from git push in openshift.

Every thing is showing ok in openshift complete and prod 1.

How can I access my application like public url so I can test?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a service, you will have to deploy a route. You can learn about routes at: [OpenShift Origin: Dev guide - Routes](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/routes.html) and [OpenShift Origin: Architecture - Routes](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/architecture/core_concepts/routes.html)